# How to add an anti-forgery token to Syncfusion grid request for data

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, syncfusion, antiforgerytoken

I'm using Syncfusion UI controls in an ASP.NET Core Razor Pages (.NET 6) application, but I'm having issues with anti-forgery validation when requesting data for the grid...

**Example:**

```
// ------------- Books.cshtml

    @page
    @model Site.Pages.BooksModel
    @using Syncfusion.EJ2
    @{
    }
    @Html.EJS().Grid("BooksIndexGrid").DataSource(dataManager => { 
        dataManager.Url("/books?handler=GetGridData");
        dataManager.Adaptor("UrlAdaptor");
    }).Columns(col =>
    {
                col.Field("title").Add();
    }).AllowPaging().AllowSorting().Render()

//-------------  Books.cshtml.cs

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.RazorPages;

namespace Site.Pages
{
    public class BooksModel : PageModel
    {
        private readonly IMediator _mediator;

        public BooksModel(IMediator mediator)
        {
            _mediator = mediator;
        }

        public void OnGet()
        {
        }

        public async Task<JsonResult> OnPostGetGridDataAsync(DataManagerRequest dm)
        {
            //Filtering logic removed for brevity

            var data = await _mediator.Send(new GetListOfBooksRequest());

            return new JsonResult(new { result = data, count = data.Count() });
        }
    }
}
```

The example above returns a 400 error code because it requests the data using a POST method and the Anti-forgery token is not present in the request.

**How do I add the required Anti-forgery token to the request to read the data?**

Ive found [this article on creating a custom adapter](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/documentation/grid/how-to/perform-crud-operation-using-anti-forgery-token), but it only seems to cover CUD and not CRUD:

I know I can disable the check for the anti-forgery token, but do not wish to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the same approach used in this [forum](https://www.syncfusion.com/forums/151450/mvc-ejsej2-call-all-action-methods-with-antiforgerytoken) and implement custom adapter from where you can send the anti-forgery token on performing CRUD actions.

This is demonstrated in the below code snippet:

```
window.customAdaptor = new ej.data.UrlAdaptor();

customAdaptor = ej.base.extend(customAdaptor, {

    processResponse: function (data, ds, query, xhr, request, changes) {
        request.data = JSON.stringify(data);
        return ej.data.UrlAdaptor.prototype.processResponse.call(this, data, ds, query, xhr, request, changes)
    },
    insert: function (dm, data, tableName) {
        return {
            url: dm.dataSource.insertUrl || dm.dataSource.crudUrl || dm.dataSource.url,
            data: jQuery.param({
                __RequestVerificationToken: document.getElementsByName("__RequestVerificationToken")[0].value,
                value: data,
                table: tableName,
                action: 'insert'
            }),
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
       }
    },
    remove: function(dm, keyField, value, tableName, query) {
        return {
            url: dm.dataSource.removeUrl || dm.dataSource.crudUrl || dm.dataSource.url,
            data: jQuery.param({
                __RequestVerificationToken: document.getElementsByName("__RequestVerificationToken")[0].value,
                key: value,
                keyColumn: keyField,
                table: tableName,
                action: 'remove'
            }),
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
        };
    },
    update: function (dm, keyField, value, tableName) {
        return {
            url: dm.dataSource.updateUrl || dm.dataSource.crudUrl || dm.dataSource.url,
            data: jQuery.param({
                __RequestVerificationToken: document.getElementsByName("__RequestVerificationToken")[0].value,
                value: value,
                table: tableName,
                action: 'insert'
            }),
            contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'
        };
    },
});

var dataManger3 = new ej.data.DataManager({
    url: "Home/GetHierachyGridData",
    crudUrl: "Home/CrudUpdate",
    adaptor: customAdaptor,
    crossDomain: true
});
```

I have modified the shared sample based on this for your reference. You can find it below as well:

Sample: https://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/Sample1Updated-486561763

More details on the custom adapter can be found in [the documentation](https://ej2.syncfusion.com/javascript/documentation/grid/data-binding/#custom-adaptor).